# Infinity loop in c# winform

Tags: c#, winforms, loops

I'm need infinity loop in my C# winform app

`while(true)` is not working.
I'm heard about timer, but I don't know how to use it for infinity loop
Im want to run this code in loop

````
 BackColor = Color.White;
 Thread.Sleep(1000);
 BackColor = Color.Black;
 Thread.Sleep(1000);```
````

Comment: What do you need the loop for?

Comment: Please provide more information for your question e.g. sample code

Comment: What do you mean by `not working`?

Comment: @Chetan while(true) is just making winform not starting

Comment: use [System.Windows.Forms.Timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.timer?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) with 1000ms `Interval`. Its `Tick` event will do what you want.

Comment: But how to use it as loop?

Comment: @Bartexpro if you want just change the bg no need for loop. Timer will always run and do what you want with 1 sec period.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here i made a sample for you. It will change `BackColor` with 1 second period.

You can control it with `_changeBackGround` or you can just stop timer with `_tmr.Stop()`

```
private readonly Timer _tmr = new Timer { Interval = 1000 };
private bool _changeBackGround = true;

public MainFrom()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BackColor = Color.White;
            _tmr.Tick += _tmr_Tick;
            _tmr.Start();
        }
private void _tmr_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (_changeBackGround)
            {
                if (BackColor == Color.White)
                {
                    BackColor = Color.Black;
                }
                else
                {
                    BackColor = Color.White;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you, im slightly edited this scriot and its working

Comment: @Bartexpro i tried to write it editable as possible as i can for you. Happy to see its working. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

As you've noticed, you can't use an infinite loop in WinForms, since that doesn't allow the UI event loop to run and process things.

So,

```
while(true) {
 BackColor = Color.White;
 Thread.Sleep(1000);
 BackColor = Color.Black;
 Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
```

can be reformulated as a Timer running with interval 1000 whose `Tick` event does

```
BackColor = BackColor == Color.White ? Color.Black : Color.White;
```

i.e., every time the tick runs, you look at whether the background is currently black, and if so, turn it to white, and vice versa.

You can of course also do this with a separate variable keeping track of which color you want to go for.

Comment: Im created timer with interval 1000, and when i used BackColor = BackColor == Color.White ? Color.Black : Color.White; back color is always black

Comment: Then it could be you'll need that additional variable after all.